# Are we able to get the active, dead letter, transfer dead letter message count for a topic at a particular point of time?

Tags: azure, messaging, azure-servicebus-topics, dead-letter

In this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#dlq-message-count), it is mentioned that is not possible to get dead letter msg count at a topic level since the messages are transferred to the subscriptions within a second. I am just wondering are we able to get the count of active messages, transfer dead letter messages at topic level using this Assemble `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` at a particular time.

In the service bus explorer, I always see these counts as zero except scheduled msg count[image: Service Explorer Topic level counts]

In Azure portal we have to set the time range to see the count details
[image: AzurePortalGraph]

So my doubt is are we able to get the active, dead letter, transfer dead letter message count for a topic at a particular time (Say at 4.27pm) or it will always returns zero unless we specify the time range (Say last 12 hours)